# ORM support for Hadoop DB

Tags: hadoop, orm

I'm trying to bootstrap an application using Hadoop and Spring (MVC, IOC, Data, Security ). I'm wondering which ORM fits with those technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache Gora open source framework provides an in-memory data model and persistence for big data. Gora supports persisting to column stores, key value stores, document stores and RDBMSs, and analyzing the data with extensive Apache Hadoop™ MapReduce support. - See more at: http://gora.apache.org/#sthash.aHUqfiFl.dpuf